# Why $d/dt |_{t=0} (\operatorname{exp}(\operatorname{ad} tX))Y = (d/dt|_{t=0} (\operatorname{exp} t(\operatorname{ad}X)))Y$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading John Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds, first edition, proof of Theorem 20.19 and some question arises :

[image]

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true? I don't know what is key point for this equality.

Comment: Because $Y$ does not depend on $t$ and ${\rm ad}(tX)=t\,{\rm ad}(X).$

Comment: Thank you. Helped to increase understanding derivative with respect to time and property of $\operatorname{ad}$ ( bilinearity over $\mathbb{R}$ )